# how to only read rows with the first column containing name i

Tags: python, excel, pandas, row

I have two excel worksheets I am reading in Python.  The first worksheet has a list of companies names.  The second is a sheet with multiple of the same companies' names and data to the right that corresponds to the row.

[![Worksheet 1][1]][1]

[![Worksheet 2][2]][2]

I want to make some kind of condition, if the name in column A WS 2 matches the name in WS 1, then print the data (columns A:F WS 2) only for the rows corresponding to the name.

I am pretty new to coding, so I've been playing with it a lot without finding much luck.  Right now I don't have much code because I tried restarting again.  Been trying to use just pandas to read, sometimes I've been trying openpyxl.

```
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter as xlw
import openpyxl as xl


TickList = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Worksheet1.xlsx",sheet_name='Tickers', header=None)
stocks = TickList.values.ravel()


Data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Worksheet2.xlsx", sheet_name='Pipeline', header=None, usecols="A:F")
data = Pipeline.values.ravel()


for i in stocks:
    for t in data:
        if i == t:
            print(data)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6mXI.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vKGR.png
```

Comment: some sample data (or even images of the data for this particular problem) would be helpful. The following can be represented by data in several different ways, so we would actually need to see the data.  "The first worksheet has a list of companies names. The second is a sheet with multiple of the same companies' names and data to the right that corresponds to the row."

Comment: I have added images.  The site didn't like my images so theirs a link of them at the bottom of the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the columns in both dataframes are called `Ticker` and you can do something like `TickList.merge(Data, how='left', on='Ticker')`

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the first thing you are doing wrong is not stipulating the key value on which the "i" in stocks is meant to match on the values in "t".   Remember - "t" are the values - all of them.   You have to specify that you wish to match the value of "i" to (probably) the first column of "t".   What you appear to be doing here is akin to a vlookup without the target range properly specified.

Whilst I do not know the exact method in which the ravel() function stores the data, I have to believe something like this would be more likely to work:

```
for i in stocks:
   for t in data:
       if i == t[0]:
           print(t)
```

Comment: I tried getting rid of the ravel() function, which I was using before because it wouldn't print before without it for some reason. It seemed to just put it back into a chart like format without it.
Anyway, I don't know why but I get the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"
Do you have any idea why this might happen?  Thanks!